# how can i resolve this issue?

Tags: spring-boot, java-ee-8

Error starting

> ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
>   2019-10-17 15:44:43.968 ERROR 10460 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

```
package com.example.angular;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CrudangularApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CrudangularApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.perf</groupId>
    <artifactId>crudangular</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>crudangular</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

this is my results

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
>   2019-10-18 11:05:18.627 ERROR 11856 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.jdbc.driver
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]

I change but I have this error

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:827) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:447) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:237) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) [spring-jdbc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) [spring-jdbc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) [spring-jdbc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:320) [spring-jdbc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at

Comment: Can you post stack trace error?

Comment: The error in your updated stacktrace referes to the issues with your MySQL server.
Please check possible solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a property in your application.yaml file

`spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

It caused by the fact that MySQL changed package of the driver from `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`.